# Ways of storing user input into an array in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

today I started learning bash and I have an issue. I made a script which prompts the user to enter how many elements the want in an array and using a for loop it allows the user enter the elements till the capacity is met. **How can I store the data in an array?**.

my code:

#!/bin/bash

```
##Declaring an array to store no.Processes

declare -A execution
    
##Enter number of process
echo "Enter number of Processes: ";
read number_of_process

for ((index=0;index<$number_of_process;index++))
do
i=$(($index+1)) 
    echo "Enter burst time of P$i:";
    read execution
done
echo "Number of Processes = $i";
```

Comment: read stores into a variable (or array) a single input line. If you want to append to an array from a read variable, you would do: `execution+=("$value")`

Comment: Please can you elaborate more. I am just starting out.

Comment: BTW, arrays don't _exist_ in sh (they're an extension added by ksh, bash, zsh, etc), so why you have the `sh` tag on this question is unclear. In general, you should tag for only one shell at a time; and even when the `sh` executable is provided by bash (which is not the case everywhere: many common operating systems like Ubuntu have `sh` provided by other implementations such as dash), it turns off several features for better compatibility with the POSIX sh specification when called under that name.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the information. I did not really know about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `read` can itself be an indexed name.

```
for ((index=0; index < $number_of_processes; index++)); do
    i=$((index+1)) 
    read -p "Enter burst time of P$i:" 'execution[index]'
done
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, I suppose so. The existence of `i` confused me, but I guess that's just to present a 1-indexed facade to the user.